# Accessing array inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to return an array of values based on a key. The values I am trying to return is dependent on the key a user enters. However, when I am iterating through my for loop I am getting an error saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var obj = {
    14: ['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'k'],
    90: ['asdf','xxc' , 'd'],
    92: ['def', 'dr' , 'vvd', 'off']
}

exports.function(key) = {
     var temp = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.key.length; i++){
        temp[i] = obj.key[i];
    }
    return temp;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: `object.key` is looking for an attribute literally called `key`.  Try `obj[key]` instead

Comment: key is dependent on a user input, how can i access the array of values in this situation @KieranE

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, `object.key` is looking for an attribute literally called `key`.  If you want to access an attribute that is defined by a user's input, you have to use the `[]` syntax.  In your case, `[key]`.

Try this:

```
exports.function(key) = {
  return obj[key];
};
```

Or, in snippit form,

```js
var obj = {
    14: ['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'k'],
    90: ['asdf','xxc' , 'd'],
    92: ['def', 'dr' , 'vvd', 'off']
};

function getKey(key){
  return obj[key];
}

console.log(getKey(14))
console.log(getKey(92))
```

Comment: right, nvm my previous comment this is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
var obj = {
    14: ['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'k'],
    90: ['asdf','xxc' , 'd'],
    92: ['def', 'dr' , 'vvd', 'off']
}

function test(key) = {
    return obj[key];
};


test(14) //returns ['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'k']
test(92) //returns ['def', 'dr' , 'vvd', 'off']
```

Comment: @OP this guy was definitely before me.  But it really is that simple.